# undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass when calling gem method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to call a method from a gem that I have created but keep getting the error stated in the title. I've looked into the error but still dont know why it is occurring. When I run the file in the Command prompt it works perfectly. All I want to do it populate the method with user input and display the result in my index page. I am running the following it the command prompt:

```
irb -rubygems 

require 'unit_converter'

UnitConverter::Weight.new.conversions(1, :kg)
```

The output changes depending on what I type in but for example the output for this would be:

```
["2.20462pounds", "0.157473stone"]
```

It's only when I try and link it up to my erb file that i get the error mentioned.
To reproduce the error This is the method I am creating in my measurements_controller file:

```
def unit_converter
    @input1 = params[:value]
    @input2 = params[:unit]
    @result = UnitConverter::Weight.new.conversions(@input1.to_i , @input2)
    end
```

And in my index.html.erb file I have a form like so:

```
  <%= form_tag "/validate" do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :value %>
    <%= text_field_tag :unit %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
    <% end %>
    <%= @result %>
```

And these are my routes to link everything up

```
 get '/check', :controller=>'measurements', :action=>'index'
  post '/validate', :controller=>'measurements', :action=>'unit_converter'
```

This is the gem that I am using and conversions is the method:

```
module UnitConverter

    class ConversionError < StandardError
    end

    class Weight
    # lookup table
    CONVERSIONS = {
      kg: {
        pounds: 2.20462,
        stone: 0.157473,
      },
      pounds: { 
        kg: 0.453592,
        stone: 0.0714286
      },
      stone: {
        kg: 6.35029,
        pounds: 14
      }
    }

    def convert(value, from, to:)
      raise ConversionError, "Value is not numeric" unless value.is_a? Numeric
      raise ConversionError, "Value #{value} is not positive" unless value >= 0
      "#{value * conversion_ratio(from, to) }#{to.to_s}"
    end

    def conversions(value, unit)
        CONVERSIONS[unit].keys.map do |other_unit|
          convert(value, unit, to: other_unit)
        end
      end

    private
    def conversion_ratio(from, to)
      begin
        CONVERSIONS.fetch(from).fetch(to)
      rescue KeyError
        raise ConversionError, "Cannot convert #{from.to_s} to #{to.to_s}"
      end
    end
  end
  end
```

My full stack trace:

```
**unit_converter (0.0.0) lib/unit_converter.rb:32:in `conversions'
app/controllers/measurements_controller.rb:9:in `unit_converter'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:196:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:135:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:33:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `instrument'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:191:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:252:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:51:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:49:in `block in serve'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:837:in `call'
rack-pjax (1.1.0) lib/rack/pjax.rb:12:in `call'
remotipart (1.4.4) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:32:in `call'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:40:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:648:in `call'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:567:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:32:in `call'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:83:in `call'
webpacker (4.2.2) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:23:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.6.5) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:526:in `call'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:681:in `handle_request'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'**
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling the `conversions` method from the console, you are passing in a symbol `:kg` ... but when the method is being called in the controller, it's receiving a String.

So you just need to convert the unit of measure to a symbol, the same way you are converting the number value to an integer:

```
@result = UnitConverter::Weight.new.conversions(@input1.to_i , @input2.to_sym)
```

The error you got was b/c the lookup in your conversions table was essentially looking for `Conversions['kg']` which returns nil -- hence the "undefined method keys..." error message.

Another solution, is to use a convenience method that Rails adds to the `Hash` class: `with_indifferent_access`.

If you define your lookup table like this (I'm omitting the guts of it), then you can access this `Hash` with either String keys or Symbol keys, and doing `@input2.to_sym` won't be necessary:

```
CONVERSIONS = {
 ...
}.with_indifferent_access
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have no error now!! but for some reason nothing happens now when I press the search button.

Comment: You need to create a corresponding ERB view for your MeasurementsController#unit_converter method that will render the value of `@result`. The `@result` in your index.html.erb file can be removed, b/c the index view is only rendering the form and `@result` hasn't been calculated at that point.

Comment: even if I want it to display in my index file?

Comment: I got the result showing by creating a corresponding erb file to the unit_converter action but I want the result to display in index is that possible?

Comment: That's not the way that standard Rails controllers/views work. You'll need to use Javascript to make an AJAX request to the rails server and have it update the HTML on the index page. Rails has some built in functionality to do this stuff, I believe, I but don't use it.

I mostly use rails as an API server for single page apps, so unforutnately I can't offer anymore advice on this.